# Navigation button in JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF button with navigation rule in faces-config.xml:

```
<h:commandButton id="newzone" styleClass="lbimage" value="New Zone" action="#{bean.navigateToNewZone()}">
    <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>

// Navigate to New Zone page
public int navigateToNewZone(){
    return 11472;
}

<navigation-rule>
    <description>Navigation rule to New Zone page</description>
    <from-view-id>/ZonesList.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{ZonesController.navigateToNewZone()}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>11472</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/NewZone.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

My question is how I can simplify the navigation? I don't want to make navigation rules into faces-config.xml. Is there way to open directly new page from the JSF button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is there way to open directly new page from the JSF button?*

Just use [`<h:button>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/button.html) instead of [`<h:commandButton>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html). You don't need a POST request for that at all.

```html
<h:button value="New Zone" outcome="/NewZone.xhtml" />
```

Note that the new JSF 2.0 "implicit navigation" feature will implicitly use the "from-outcome" as "to-view-id", so you could indeed also use the "to-view-id" directly in `<h:commandButton action>` or the return value as hinted by the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `action="/NewZone.xhtml"` directly without further configuration within `faces-config.xml`.